# Process table's data in servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, html-table, jstl

I am populating a dynamic table in jsp and submitting this table to a Servlet . In Servlet all I can get is `String[]` of each column with `request.getParametersMap()` but I want to process each row's data one by one. . Any idea how to achieve this ?

My table is:

```
<form method=POST action="ProcessTableDataServlet">
   <table>
        <tr>
            <th><input type=text name=city></th>
            <th><input type=text name=employe></th>
            <th><input type=text name=salary></th>
            <th><input type=text name=companyName></th>
            <th><input type=text name=experience></th>
            <th><input type=text name=Gender></th>
            <th><input type=text name=Age></th>
            <th><input type=text name=post></th>
            <th><input type=text name=hasPassport></th>
</tr>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
           <!-- populating data dynamically -->
           <c:forEach var="result" varStatus="status" items="${list}">
             <TD>
               <input type="text" name="${status.index}" value="${result}" />
            </TD>
          </c:forEach>

           </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type=submit>
    </form>
```

Now what I want is to process each employee's data one by one, but I can't as I can get each `field[]`  like `employee[]`, `city[]`, `salary[]`, `company[]` ....etc. My question is how to process each row's data one by one?

Comment: Is there any other suggestion for this question ? I am kinda stuck here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally realized , i was going in wrong direction. Instead of populating column's data at server side why not push each row's data in array using (jquery/javascript) and then convert it in JSONArray. Once we have JSONArray object send it to server and at server side convert this JSONArray to dataBean.

Here are the steps:-
 1. Traverse whole table and push each row's data in array.
 2. Convert this array in JSON format. 
 3. Send this JSONArray Object via POST/GET to Servlet. 
 4. Servlet will convert this JSON object to a List.
 5. Each bean represents a complete table row's data and you can get any column's value by   getterMethod().

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put all the information you want to pass on inputs or using a URL to inform that to a servlet.

First, a couple of things you might want to consider:

```
1)Use only one form tag in your page instead of using one for each row.
2)Enclose the whole table within your form tag.
```

You will end up with something like this:

```
<FORM NAME="actionForm" action="ProfCourseUpdate" method='post'>
<table border="2">
<tr>
    <th>CourseID</th>
    <th>SectionNo</th>
    <th>Add Info</th>
</tr>
<% while(rs.next()){    %>  
<tr>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("CourseID") %> </td>
    <td> <%=rs.getInt("SectionNo") %> </td>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="ProfCourseUpdate" value="Update Course Info"></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
</FORM>
```

Now, with that all cleared out of the way, you might want to use a different approach. If you want your table for selecting a course/section purpose, you don't even need a form (or a submit button for that matter).

You could replace this:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="ProfCourseUpdate" value="Update Course Info"></td>
```

With this:

```
<td><a href="/ProfCourseUpdate?CourseID=<%=rs.getString("CourseID") %>&SectionNo=<%=rs.getInt("SectionNo") %>">Update</a></td>
```

This way, your ProfCourseUpdate servlet with receive the two variables needed (CourseID and SectionNo) to retrieve and update that row.

If you must use a button, you could use the same technique, but encoding CourseID and SectionNo on value. But I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Avnish for suggestion but i think i was not clear enough . Let me update my question

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to create a DTO class here,which represent your table data and you can set it your request scope in JSP.Below code snippet is given,just to provide an approach,how we can solve this problem,it is not production ready :):)

```
class Employee{

  private String name;
  private String city;
  ---------------
  ------getter && setter------

}
```

You can create list of employee in JSP page.

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Then during iteration in JSP for the list you can create object of Employee class,which represent row.

```
          <c:forEach var="result" varStatus="status" items="${list}">
             <TD>
               <input type="text" name="${status.index}" value="${result}" />
            </TD>
          <% Employee emp = new Employee(); //set the value for the current row %>
          </c:forEach>
```

Then you can set this to request scope like below,in your jsp.

```
request.setAttribute("empList",empList);
```

And later on in your servlet,you can get this List from request simply by:

```
List<Employee> empList = (List<Employee>)request.getAttribute("empList");
```

and then you can iterate empList easily,each object in empList represent a row in table,so now you do not have iterate individual array to fetch data for a row.

Comment: thanks RE350 , can you please also let me know how to set values of current row in Employee Bean without using scriptlet ?

Answer (score -1):

As re350 pointed out, use a bean (DTO) to back the data. In the loop, create a td tag for each field in the bean. Each pass through the loop is for an entire row

```
       <c:forEach var="result" varStatus="status" items="${list}">
        <tr>
            <TD>
                <input type="text" name="${status.index}" value="${result.name}" />
            </TD>
            <TD>
                <input type="text" name="${status.index}" value="${result.city}" />
            </TD>
            ...
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

**Response to comment about filling bean:**

The problem is that Expression Language (EL) and scriptlets are run on the server before the page is created. EL is better than scriptlets, but both have the same limitation. The data is changing in the browser in response to user input. EL and scriptlets cannot detect this. The only thing to do is to submit the data and parse it in the servlet.

If you try something like

```
${result.setName("Fred")}
```

it will be calculated before the page is sent to the browser.

An alternative to allowing the user to edit all the data in the table at one time is to show the data statically in the table and add a button for each row. When the button is clicked, open a new page that only edits the data for that row. Many web sites use this approach.

**Responding to comment about too many pages:**

It is not necessary to have a new page for each record. Each record will use the same page. Use the bean to populate the fields in a page that allows users to edit the values. Similar to what you are doing now, but only the data for one row needs to be displayed.

Instead of passing the entire list to the page, only send the record that is being edited.

Each row in the table will need a form with a button. Include a hidden field that identifies the record for the row. The action for each form will be the same, so only one new page needs to be created. In the servlet, retrieve the hidden field then retrieve the corresponding record. Send that record to the page for editing.

Comment: Downeyt thanks ,can you please let me know how to set values of current row in Employee Bean without using scriptlet ?

Comment: my problem is that i have such a huge table ,so for each row opening a new page and edit data for that row is not option here . Is there any way i can set Employee Bean data (after user input some data)in my jsp page ? i am bit confused here